# Why does Akka application fail with Out-of-Memory Error while executing NLP task?

Tags: scala, akka, stanford-nlp

I notice that my program has a severe memory leak (the memory consumption spirals up). I had to parallelize this NLP task (using StanfordNLP EnglishPCFG Parser and Tregex Matcher). So I built a pipeline of actors (only 6 actors for each task):

```
   val listOfTregexActors = (0 to 5).map(m => system.actorOf(Props(new TregexActor(timer, filePrinter)), "TregexActor" + m)) 
   val listOfParsers = (0 to 5).map(n => system.actorOf(Props(new ParserActor(timer, listOfTregexActors(n), lp)), "ParserActor" + n)) 
   val listOfSentenceSplitters  = (0 to 5).map(j => system.actorOf(Props(new SentenceSplitterActor(listOfParsers(j), timer)), "SplitActor" + j))
```

My actors are pretty standard. They need to stay alive to process all the information (there's no poisonpill along the way). The memory consumption goes up and up, and I don't have a single clue of what's wrong. If I run single-thread, the memory consumption would be just fine. I read it somewhere that if actors don't die, nothing inside will be released. Should I manually release things?

There are two heavy-lifting actors:

https://github.com/windweller/parallelAkka/blob/master/src/main/scala/blogParallel/ParserActor.scala
https://github.com/windweller/parallelAkka/blob/master/src/main/scala/blogParallel/TregexActor.scala

I wonder if it could be Scala's closure or other mechanism that retains too much information, and GC can't collect it somehow.

Here's part of TregexActor:

```
def receive = {
    case Match(rows, sen) =>
      println("Entering Pattern matching: " + rows(0))
      val result = patternSearching(sen)
      filePrinter ! Print(rows :+ sen.toString, result)
  }

  def patternSearching(tree: Tree):List[Array[Int]] = {
    val statsFuture = search(patternFuture, tree)
    val statsPast = search(patternsPast, tree)

    List(statsFuture, statsPast)
  }

  def search(patterns: List[String], tree: Tree) = {
    val stats =  Array.fill[Int](patterns.size)(0)

    for (i <- 0 to patterns.size - 1) {
      val searchPattern = TregexPattern.compile(patterns(i))
      val matcher = searchPattern.matcher(tree)
      if (matcher.find()) {
        stats(i) = stats(i) + 1
      }
      timer ! PatternAddOne
    }
    stats
  }
```

Or if my code checks out, could it be StanfordNLP parser or tregex matcher's memory leak?? Is there a strategy to manually release memory or do I need to kill those actors after a while and assign their mailbox tasks to a new actor to release memory? (If so, how?)

[image]

---

After some struggling with profiling tools, I finally was able to use VisualVM with IntelliJ. Here are the snapshots. GC never ran.

[image]

The other is Heap Dump:

[image]

---

Summary of pipeline:

Raw Files -> SentenceSplit Actors (6) -> Parser Actors (6) -> Tregex Actors (6) -> File Output Actors (done)

Patterns are defined in Entry.scala file: https://github.com/windweller/parallelAkka/blob/master/src/main/scala/blogParallel/Entry.scala

Comment: Try using visualVM which will tell you which class is causing this. Most likely your Actor's mailboxes are getting filled up because different actors have different service time in your pipeline. Basically imagine a fast producer and a slow consumer. The mailbox of the slow consumer will cause of MemoryException.

Comment: It seems to me you're just listing a few things at random that might leak. Have you investigated where the memory is going? e.g with hprof?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta You are right. That may very well be the issue but the data waiting to be processed is only 320mb. It can't take over more than 80gb heap space. I just downloaded VisualVM. I ran my Akka program with sbt command not from any application. I can't find my program on VisualVM's left sidebar!

Comment: @WindDweller, without some evidence of what the memory is being consumed by, you (and we) are just wandering around in the dark. The good thing about the disparity between data size and VM size is that probably all the leaking memory will be in many many instances of one or two classes. Please try and get some information on where /what is consuming the memory

Comment: @Paul Yes I understand. I'm trying to use VisualVM but encountered the problem mentioned above. All tutorials I found only teach to run VisualVM on Java Server (even local server like Glassfish or Tomcat).

Comment: OK. How about hprof, then?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta the profiled result is above!

Comment: @Paul I ran VisualVM with IntelliJ and the result is above. It seems like `regexPattern` and `lexparser` two classes took a lot of memory (though not as much as that `float[]`). They belong to `TregexActor` and `ParserActor`. Also GC never ran.

Comment: You need to dig further and find out where the float[] allocations are being made

Comment: @MrWiggles any suggestions how? I never used `float[]` in my code...

Comment: Where are `patternFuture` and `patternsPast` defined ? Can you put a summary of your pipeline i.e., which actor is sending a what message to which other actor in the chain?

Comment: You might not have, but some code you're using will be doing.  The profiler should offer options for digging into where the allocations were made

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta I described my pipeline (it's very very very simple). `patternFuture` and `patternPast` are defined in `Entry.scala` file here: https://github.com/windweller/parallelAkka/blob/master/src/main/scala/blogParallel/Entry.scala. I doubt that's the issue though.

Comment: Can you add some actor logging and log start and stop of your actors? then you'll know if newly created actors exit or not.

Comment: @Ashalynd I did not create any new actor. I created 18 actors at the very beginning and kept using them. There's no killing or actor creation in the process.

Comment: @MrWiggles Got it. The humongous amount of `float[]` is from `ExhaustivePCFGParser` which means it's from Parser Actor. But what can I do with this information??

Answer (score 1):

This may not the correct answer but I don't have enough space to write it in the comment.

Try moving the actor creating inside your a Companion object.

```
  val listOfTregexActors = (0 to 5).map(m => system.actorOf(Props(new TregexActor(timer, filePrinter)), "TregexActor" + m))
  val listOfParsers = (0 to 5).map(n => system.actorOf(Props(new ParserActor(timer, listOfTregexActors(n), lp)), "ParserActor" + n))
  val listOfSentenceSplitters = (0 to 5).map(j => system.actorOf(Props(new SentenceSplitterActor(listOfParsers(j), timer)), "SplitActor" + j))
```

OR don't use the `new` to create your actors.

I suspect when your create the app you are closing your `App` which is preventing the GC to collect any garbage.

You can easily verify if this is the issue by looking at the heap on Visual VM once you have made the change.

Also, how long does it take for you to run out of memory and what is the max. heap memory you are giving your JVM ?

EDIT
See - Creating Actors with Props [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html)

Few other things to consider:

1. Make sure your actor are not dying and restarted automatically.
2. Create your NLP objects outside your actors and pass them when you create your actors.
3. Use [Akka router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html) instead of your hashing logic to distribute work between different actors.

Comment: I'm giving a huge amount of memory (about 80gb). It takes 2 - 3 hours to run out of memory. I had to use `new` because I need to pass in arguments when I construct those actors. What do you mean by moving into a `Companion object`? The `Entry.scala` is an object! This does seem to be a more possible solution!

Comment: Please see my Edit above. It tells you different ways to create actors. 80GB is a lot of memory IMO, so you definitely have a leak in your system. Finally from VisualVM try to do an explicit GC (by clicking on the "Perform GC" button). See if your heap memory goes down after this.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I was able to optimize a whole lot more (especially the moving NLP part out of actor part). Thank you! I noticed the memory usage pattern is different when I ran program through IntelliJ (with VisualVM open) and when I ran with SBT from commandline. If I run from commandline, memory never goes down (be around 50gb). If I run from IntelliJ, memory will be around 40gb. However, either way I ran out of heap space before task was finished.

Comment: What happens you do an explicit "Perform GC" ? Does the heap space go down ? Can you give an estimate of size of your new gen and old gen?

Answer (score 0):

I see these pieces of code in your actors:

```
 val cleanedSentences = new java.util.ArrayList[java.util.List[HasWord]]()
```

Are these objects ever freed? If not, that might explain why memory goes up. Especially taking into account that you return these newly created objects (e.g. in `cleanSentence` method).

UPDATE: you might try, instead of creating new object, modify the object you have received instead, and then flag it's availability as the response (instead of sending the new object back), though from the point of thread-safety it might also be funky. Other option might be to use an external storage (e.g. database or Redis key-value store), put the resulting sentences there and send "sentence cleaned" as a reply, so that the client can then access the sentence from that key-value store or DB.

In general, using **mutable objects** (like java.util.List) which might potentially be leaked in actors is not a good idea, so it might be worth redesigning your application to use **immutable objects** whenever possible.

E.g. your cleanSentence method would then look like:

```
def cleanSentence(sentences: List[HasWord]): List[HasWord] = {
    import TwitterRegex._

    sentences.filter(ref =>
        val word = ref.word() // do not call same function several times
        !word.contains("#") && 
        !word.contains("@") &&  
        !word.matches(searchPattern.toString())
      )
  }
```

You can convert your java.util.List to Scala list (before sending it to actor) in the following manner:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val javaList:java.util.List[HasWord] = ...
javaList.asScala
```

Comment: It might be a problem but how to free this?

Comment: In theory, in Java you free the object if 1) it gets out of scope or 2) you explicitly assign `null` to it.

Comment: One other solution might be not to create the new object, but modify the object you have received instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I assigned `null` to this. However, I doubt it's the main issue though. I read another post saying GC will not be performed when there are many threads. My profiled result also shows almost 0 GC activity.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but assigning null is more to say GC that this object can be freed. Read my other suggestion, don't know how easily it would be for you to change code in that manner (using a separate storage instead of sending objects back and forth)

Comment: One other option: send Scala lists (immutable) instead of Java mutable lists.

Comment: I tried. Stanford NLP Parser only takes in `java.util.List`. Even if I use Scala lists, I still have to convert it into `java.util.List` in the end. Sorry.

Comment: Converting is OK, but you should convert these Lists to Scala lists when sending them to actors and back. Then you send immutable objects, which are easier for GC to be freed.